# TabLayout with two tabs one 75% other 25%

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I am working on a screen that has two tabs:

- The first one must have a width of 75% of the screen.
- The second one must have a width of 25% of the screen.

Example:

[image]

This is how I have defined my TabLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
app:tabMode="scrollable"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
app:tabTextColor="@color/darkGrey" >
```

How can I customise my tabs layout to fix the desired width?

Comment: Is it necessary to use (depricated) `TabLayout`?

Comment: @Boken Where are you seeing that `TabLayout` is deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programtically. Add them separately for different tabs.

```
LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(YOUR_TAB_NUMBER));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = YOUR_WEIGHT; // e.g. 0.5f
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: those who down voted please care to explain why down voted?

Answer (score -1):

For `LinearLayout` you can use `weight` mechanism:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#0f0" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00F" />

</LinearLayout>
```

First `View` has weight `3`, and second has `1`. So together has `4` (first 75%, second 25%)